# Laravel URL issue

Tags: css, laravel, url

In my source code of Blade file of CSS include URL is like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css">
```

But I am getting below URL in page source of browser

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

Why I am getting this ? How can I remove `public` from the URL ?

Comment: Check your APP_URL value in the environment file. The host part will be set from it, so if you need something different update the variable at `.env`.

Comment: @Pusparaj, There is no APP_URL value in the environment file.

Comment: setting the APP_URL to http://127.0.0.1:8000 might help, do you have this environment behind a web server like Apache or Nginx? To get to the app homepage do you go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000/public?

Comment: @AlecJoy, I used `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in .env file. But it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `public` in the path because you're accessing your site the same way `http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/`.

You need to change how your server serves the application.

Comment: You have to change the root of your server to be your-app/public folder

Comment: @SantiBarbat, how to change ?

Comment: @abuabu you need to lookout how to configure a vhost in xampp here is one on windows https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/

Comment: @N69S, I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: @abuabu which server are you using ? apache, nginx or are you using the built in serve command ?

Comment: @N69S, apache. I think solution is easy. But I never faced this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu can you add your apache vhost config to your question ?

Comment: @N69S, I have no vhost.

Comment: @abuabu how are you using apache then ?

Comment: @N69S, I am using Linux Mint. I put Laravel files inside `/var/www/html/` directory.

Comment: @N69S, This app is hosted in a shared hosting. Previous developer renamed `server.php` to `index.php` and modified .htaccess file. I am trying to install this app in my local machine. In my machine other laravel applications are running well. So there is no issue in my machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

asset() function points to the public folder. For your css file to work make a 'frontend' folder in the public directory

Comment: you may look for setBasePath($rootDirectory)

Comment: Where can I get it ?